# Best approach to bind to events occurring inside a component

Tags: angular

Angular4 app:
I am using a videogular2 library(or let say just  elem) in a component call it CompA, where CompA then used inside CompB.

I need to subscribe to the events of videogular(or video elem) inside CompA such that if play/pause occurs it will emit or could listen in the ServiceX.

First of all I am not getting solution exact to my problem, second I want to what will be best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for [**videogular2 here**](https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/getting-started/using-the-api.html), you need to bind to the `onPlayerReady` event on the `vg-player` component. Something like this:

```
<vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
    <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" controls>
        <source src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</vg-player>
```

You will then get an `event` in the `onPlayerReady` event handler. This event basically is an API that exposes `getDefaultMedia().subscriptions`. On that, you can subscribe to `Observable`s like `play` and `pause` [**listed here**](https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/getting-started/using-the-api.html). Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';

import { PlayerStateService } from './player-state.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  api: VgAPI;

  constructor(private playerState: PlayerStateService) { }

  onPlayerReady(api: VgAPI) {
    console.log('playerReady');
    this.api = api;
    this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.play.subscribe(
        (event) => {
          this.playerState.updatePlayerState('play');
        }
    );

    this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.pause.subscribe(
        (event) => {
          this.playerState.updatePlayerState('pause');
        }
    );

  }
}
```

Now that you get to know that the player has paused or resumed, you can easily create a Shared Service, with a `BehaviorSubject` on it. And every time there's a change in the status of the player, you can set a new value on that `BehaviorSubject` by calling the `next` method on it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerStateService {

  private state: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  public state$: Observable<string> = this.state.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updatePlayerState(playerState: string) {
    this.state.next(playerState);
  }

}
```

And you can then subscribe to it in some other component where you want to listen to these state changes in the player.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { PlayerStateService } from './player-state.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Current state of the player is {{ playerState$ | async }}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  playerState$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private playerState: PlayerStateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.playerState$ = this.playerState.state$;
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/videogular-eg-for-stack-overflow?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, can you explain how PlayerStateService listens to player status?

Comment: Thumbs up friend, seem I commented before you edited. You answered exactly the approach I want to see, like you were in my mind when posted the question. Thank you. @SiddAjmera